# How to show database records in bootstrap nav dropdown?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I Have a table called customer in which i have customer records.

Then i have table called Site, in which i have some two fields customer_id and site_key. Where site key is random generated license key.

Now I want to do something like this:

I want to show a nav bar in which the customer logged in can have a dropdown which will have its keys.

What i mean to say is A customer may have multiple site key so i want to fetch all the keys of that customer and show it in top nav bar dropdown.

I know the code for selecting the data from database, but i dont know how to display it the way i want.

Please Help

The Model Code:

```
public function get_user_license()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->join('tenant', 'sites.tenant_id = tenant.id');
    $this->db->from('sites');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result(); 
    return $result; 
}
```

Comment: see i can join two tables my customer table and the site table and get resultant var_dump, but next what? How to display it

Comment: suppose i have an array $data in which i have the site keys but how to display them as dropdown

Comment: Have a look at: [Generating Query Results - CodeIgniter User Guide](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

Comment: @Aziz i know that but my concern is showing them in bootstap dropdown like this http://getbootstrap.com/components/#

Comment: Post your current basic result function and we'll figure out how to apply bootstrap to it

Comment: @Aziz i have added my select code it give me all the customer and the keys from database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104256/discussion-between-rajan-and-aziz).

Comment: @Aziz codeigniter official doc's now moved here. http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Comment: You have your data, you know what HTML structure you need to create from it – so, where’s the problem?

Comment: Yeah i got it now @CBroe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For controller

```
$this->data['sites']= $this->customer_user_m->get_user_license();
```

For model

```
             public function get_user_license()
        {


         $id = $this->session->userdata('id');

         $this->db->select('*');
         $this->db->where('tenant.id',$id);
         $this->db->join('tenant', 'sites.tenant_id = tenant.id');
         $this->db->from('sites');
         $query = $this->db->get();
         $result = $query->result(); 
         return $result; 
        }
```

The View:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">
        <?php

        foreach($sites as $site)
        {

        echo "<li>".$site->site_key."</li>";
        }
```